# What's the difference between PlanSys2 and Moveit Task Constructor

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. At the moment I want to use one of these tools to write a task scheduler for my robotic system. But let's imagine that MTC is already ported to ROS2 and still. Can the MTC be used as a PlanSys2 subroutine or should they be viewed as competing tools.

P.S. If the question is not clear, I will reformulate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390965/what%27s-the-difference-between-plansys2-and-moveit-task-constructor/) by [BillFinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/86336/billfinger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found answers to many questions by reading this topic on ROS Discourse

https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-planning-system-1st-anniversary/18224/9

---

Originally posted by [BillFinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/86336/billfinger/) with karma: 16 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0